# ModuleNotFoundError trying to import from the same folder

Tags: python

I have a folder with a bunch of pythons files...

ie.

```
folder1
--py1.py
--py2.py
```

After getting into folder1 from the command line if i try to run py1.py which for simplicity's sake just has one import

```
from folder1.py2 import somefunc
```

i get a message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'`

I've tried relative imports

I've also tries adding this directory to the path

```
sys.path.append(".")
```

These files are in the same folder, i'm executing from within the directory. How can i fix this?

Comment: Try using `from .py2 import somefunc` instead

Comment: @BastienAntoine I've tried using relative import already. same issue

Comment: `sys.path.append(".")` adds _dot_ to `sys.path`. Did you try to add real path?

Comment: have you tried from py2 import somefunc (without the dot)?

Comment: if i do relative import i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.py2'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: And have you tried simply `from py2 import somefunc` ?